# How to order a list of URLs in Google Spreadsheet in a cascade structure?

Tags: url, google-sheets

Let’s say I have a list of URLs like this:

```
https://moz.com/
https://moz.com/about
https://moz.com/about/contact
https://moz.com/about/jobs
https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo
https://moz.com/blog
https://moz.com/blog/category/advanced-seo
https://moz.com/blog/advanced-seo/technical
https://moz.com/blog/advanced-seo/content
https://moz.com/blog/googles-walled-garden
https://moz.com/blog/local-search-ranking-factors-survey-results-2017
https://moz.com/explorer
https://moz.com/help
https://moz.com/help/guides
https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-pro-overview
```

And I wanted it to be displayd in different columns according to the depth of the structure. Like each part of the URL is a level in the sites hierarchy and I want to visualize the hierarchy as such:

```
https://moz.com/
    https://moz.com/about   
        https://moz.com/about/contact
        https://moz.com/about/jobs
    https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo
    https://moz.com/blog
        https://moz.com/blog/advanced-seo
            https://moz.com/blog/advanced-seo/technical
            https://moz.com/blog/advanced-seo/content
        https://moz.com/blog/googles-walled-garden
        https://moz.com/blog/local-search-ranking-factors-survey-results-2017
    https://moz.com/explorer
    https://moz.com/help
        https://moz.com/help/guides
        https://moz.com/help/guides/moz-pro-overview
```

How can I do this? I have already tried utilizing the split function for this but that does not work because it just splits the different parts of the URL into different columns and not the whole URL into the accordant column.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the range with links is `A:A`:

1. Put the formula `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(REGEXMATCH(A2,$A$1:A1), true))*1` in B2 and drag it down
2. Put the formula `=REPT("      ",B1)&A1` in C1 and drag it down.

[image]

**Edit1**

Here's the single formula to do the same:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(rept("      ",MMULT(
--(REGEXMATCH(A1:A15,TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(A1:A15,1,)))),SIGN(A1:A15<>""))-1)&A1:A15)`

**Edit2**

> this is a brilliant solution thank you alot. However it seems I run
>   into problems with sites that include .html at the very end
>   (moz.com/about.html but moz.com/about/contact.html and so on). Any
>   ideas how to bypass that?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(rept("      ",MMULT(--(REGEXMATCH(A1:A15,REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(A1:A15,1,)),"\.html$",""))),
SIGN(A1:A15<>""))-1)&A1:A15)`

Notes:

- the formula also replaces ".html" from the end of a string.

Comment: this is a brilliant solution thank you alot. However it seems I run into problems with sites that include .html at the very end (https://moz.com/about.html but https://moz.com/about/contact.html and so on). Any ideas how to bypass that?

Comment: Hi, @Castor. Please see the **Edit2**

Comment: Hi @Max Makhrov I have desperately tried to adapt your formula so that I can use URLs with .html in the end and just display the hierarchy level as you did in your first example.

I came up with this by trying to include the regexreplace: `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(D4,"\.html$",""),$D$3:D3), true))*1`

Comment: Update to my comment: I figured that it works if I include regexmatch also for the second range meaning:`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(D3,"\.html$",""),REGEXREPLACE($D2:D$3,"\.html$","")), true))*1` However I always get "1" for the main domain instead of "0".